# Discord.js random number

Tags: discord.js

If you don't mind me asking, I've been trying to find out a way to have a discord user say (prefix)randomnumber and then 2 parameters like 1 10 and it picks a random number such as 7. Does anyone know of a way to do this in java script?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```js
Math.floor(Math.random()*second_parameter)+first_parameter
```

and if we take the full code

```js
const args = message.split(' ')
if(args[0] === `${prefix}randomnumber`){
    message.channel.send(Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(args[2]))+parseInt(args[1]))
```

Comment: So if we take my full code, 

`module.exports = {
  name: "random",
  category: 'Fun',
  description: "Random number",
run: async (client, message, args) => {
 let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!member) {
      const args = message.split(' ')
       message.channel.send(Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(args[2]))+parseInt(args[1])
       )}}}`
What would make this work to the thing I needed help with above

Comment: You mean this didn't worked? Tell me if there are any errors